# How to reduce unnecessary threads in MapReduce tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, mapreduce, task, jobs

I'm writing a very simple mapreduce job to test how much threads concurrency run, the code is below:

```
    System.out.println("--42-- thread num in main is : " + Thread.activeCount());
    JobConf jconf2 = new JobConf(TestPermission.class);
    System.out.println("--44-- thread num in main is : " + Thread.activeCount());

    jconf2.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    jconf2.setMapOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
    System.out.println("--48-- thread num in main is : " + Thread.activeCount());

    jconf2.setMapperClass(Map1.class);
    System.out.println("--55-- thread num in main is : " + Thread.activeCount());

    jconf2.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    System.out.println("--58-- thread num in main is : " + Thread.activeCount());
    jconf2.setOutputFormat(NothingOutputFormat.class);
    System.out.println("--60-- thread num in main is : " + Thread.activeCount());

    jconf2.set("mapred.map.tasks", String.valueOf(1));
    System.out.println("--63-- thread num in main is : " + Thread.activeCount());
    jconf2.set("mapred.reduce.tasks", String.valueOf(0));
    System.out.println("--65-- thread num in main is : " + Thread.activeCount());

    jconf2.set("mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies", "0");
    System.out.println("--68-- thread num in main is : " + Thread.activeCount());
    jconf2.set("mapreduce.tasktracker.http.threads", "0");
    System.out.println("--70-- thread num in main is : " + Thread.activeCount());
    jconf2.set("mapreduce.jobtracker.jobinit.threads", "0");
    System.out.println("--72-- thread num in main is : " + Thread.activeCount());


    TextInputFormat.setInputPaths(jconf2, new Path(args[0]));
    System.out.println("--76-- thread num in main is : " + Thread.activeCount());
    NothingOutputFormat.setOutputPath(jconf2, new Path(args[1]));
    System.out.println("--78-- thread num in main is : " + Thread.activeCount());

    Path output_path = new Path(args[1]);
    FileSystem fs = output_path.getFileSystem(jconf2);
    System.out.println("--82-- thread num in main is : " + Thread.activeCount());
    FsPermission fper = new FsPermission(
            FsAction.ALL, //user action
            FsAction.ALL, //group action
            FsAction.ALL);

    giveAllAthority(fs, output_path, fper);

    System.out.println("---90---thread num in main is : " + Thread.activeCount());

    JobClient.runJob(jconf2);
    System.out.println("--93-- thread num in main is : " + Thread.activeCount());
```

When I run the job, the result is below:

```
--42-- thread num in main is : 1
--44-- thread num in main is : 1
--48-- thread num in main is : 1
--55-- thread num in main is : 1
--58-- thread num in main is : 1
--60-- thread num in main is : 1
--63-- thread num in main is : 1
--65-- thread num in main is : 1
--68-- thread num in main is : 1
--70-- thread num in main is : 1
--72-- thread num in main is : 1
--76-- thread num in main is : 3
--78-- thread num in main is : 3
--82-- thread num in main is : 3
---90---thread num in main is : 6

    ............

--93-- thread num in main is : 13
```

I'm confused，Why the active threads increase in line 76/90/93. My Job don't need shuffle, so there are no reduce. So if these threads are unnecessary， I want to know how to close them.

Comment: You shouldn't just assume they're unnecessary. Unless you can show that there are excessive threads in play, there's probably nothing strange.

Comment: Because I have run multithreads in my map task,  and the resource in cluster is not enough, so I want to reduce some threads  that started by MapReduce frame, but I'm not sure which threads are unnecessary to my project.
(My project only have map progress, don't need shuffle/sort/merge, using yarn)

Comment: Then you need to find out whether you have unnecessary threads. Showing us a couple of lines telling `thread num in main is : 13` isn't enough information for us to give you an answer, so you're going to have to investigate it yourself, for example with a profiler.

Comment: The map tasks can not start at the same time when I set this jconf2.set("mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores", "8");
but when I set it to 1, all map tasks can start simultaneously

Comment: That's still not useful information.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for your answer, I think I need to find solution in mapreduce source code.

Comment: I'd start with documentation and profiling myself.

Comment: I set vcores to 8 because each map have started 21 threads (I have started 8 threads in my getReadRecorder method),  but when do this , all map can not start at the same time (it is because there are no enough resource in cluster, the cluster only have 200 cores, my job have 128 maps, and each map start 21 threads and apply for 8 vcores, totally 1024 vcores), result in a long time job running.
When I set vcores to 1, though all map task can start simultaneously, but the single map task runs slowly (because the vcores is not enough for each map), also  result in a long time job running.

Comment: I suspect whether MapReduce has some thread pools  for merge/sort/, or some other progress that i don't need, I can close these thread pools. After do this,  each map task has less threads, so i can set vcores to a low number to guarantee the single map’s running, while all map tasks can start simultaneously.
From the code in question, the mapreduce frame start 13 threads, where these threads being started, and what these threads doing, i don't know, i think i can only read mapreduce source code to know this.